# Is it possible to easily update files your own repo from two different forked repos without pulling everything from the forks?

Tags: git, github

In order to explain what I am trying to do I am using a book analogy with respect to GitHub repositories:

Lets say I had two books, and I wanted to take some pages from both books and put those pages into one big book. Then I wanted the pages that I took to update every time someone updated the original books. Like if someone wrote something new on of the pages that I chose to add to my book their new text would show up in my own.

I've tried using modules, but it looks like this requires that I copy and update the entire repo into my own instead of just updating the particular files that I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you intended to go with your analogy, but I think it does not matter.  The short answer is "no", and the reason is simple:  Git is not about *files*.  Git is really all about *commits*.

(But some of this may depend on what you mean by "pulling everything".)

It's true that commits *contain* files, and when we are working with some Git repository, we probably care about files.  But Git doesn't: it cares about *commits*.  Its fundamental unit of storage is the commit.  Many of its operations work from commits—including all of those that transfer things from one Git to another.  Even the commands that can deal with files mostly<sup>1</sup> copy files from a work-area to Git's *index*, or from the index to the work-area ... and the index is perhaps best summarize as *the proposed next commit*.

The upshot of all of this is that *you* can work with files all you like, but *Git* likes to put all those files into a new snapshot—a commit—and then work with commits.  If there are two GitHub repositories A and B that you'd like to get stuff from, you must use `git fetch` with two URLs, pointing to those two repositories, to fill your local Git repository up with any new commits from both A and B.

Whether that constitutes "pulling everything" depends on your definition of "pulling everything".  Note that you would not use `git pull` to achieve this state, because that means *fetch, then merge*.  Merge will *combine* commits, which may not be what you want.  To get to ths state, where you have the latest from both A and B, you would just use `git fetch` twice: once to get the latest from A, and once to get the latest from B.

The issue now becomes this:  A commit is not *just* a snapshot of files; it also remembers the raw hash ID of its immediate predecessor(s), which Git calls *parent* commits.  Since each commit remembers its parent(s), Git can always start at the *last* commit in some sequence of commits, and work backwards: the commit with hash `H` is preceded by the commit with hash `G`.  From `G`, Git finds `F`, which finds `E` and then `D` and so on, all the way back to the first commit.

The history in a Git repository, then, is simply the commits.  It's the *chain of commits* formed by starting at the end—the commit whose hash ID is stored in some name—and working backwards.  If you start at *all* branch names, and work backwards, you get all branch history:

```
                I <-J  <--branch1 (HEAD)
               /
... <-F <-G <-H
               \
                K <-L  <--branch2
```

Running `git merge` tells your Git: *Use the history formed by these backwards-pointing arrows to find a common commit among two or more branches.*  For instance, with the above, commits `J` and `L` reach a common shared point at `H`.  *Then, having found the common shared commit, compare the snapshots in the three commits, so that we see what I changed on `branch1`, and what they changed on `branch2`.  That is, diff commit `H` against my `J`, then, separately diff `H` against their `L`.  Then, combine the differences and make a new commit `M` from the combined results.  Since my branch is `branch1`, update the name `branch1` so that it points to this new merge commit.*

If all goes well, the result is:

```
       I--J
      /    \
...--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
      \    /
       K--L   <-- branch2
```

where the snapshot in `M` is the result of taking all the files from `H`, applying all the changes seen from `H` to `J`, applying—with redundancies removed—all the changes seen from `H` to `L`, and committing the resulting file-set.  (So here, Git *is* operating on files—but always on a complete *set* of files, from three separate commits!  It's the commits that matter; the files only matter to the extent that the commits are made out of them.)

It's up to you to think about whether and how `git merge`, or some other internal Git operations—most of which operate on commits—might be useful to whatever your ultimate problem really is.  Git is just a set of tools here, not a solution.  Indeed, for almost all problems, Git is not a *solution*, it's just a tool-set.

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, `git checkout branch` or `git checkout hash` first fills the index from the commit you just selected, then replaces work-tree files so that they match the copies in the index.  That way the current commit that you just checked out matches the proposed next commit in the index, *and* you can see all the files, which are now in ordinary everyday file format in your work-tree.  The `git add file` command copies a file, which you presumably just updated, from the work-tree into the special Git-format version in the index, ready to go into the next commit.

The word "mostly" needs to be here because `git checkout` has some specialized sub-modes, and you can `git show` individual blob objects from individual commits, and so on.